# PouchDB continuous replication without longpoll

Tags: pouchdb, couchdb-2.0

Is it possible to have continuous replication without using the longpoll feature. We are going to have around 300 clients connecting to a CouchDB server proxied via a Nodejs/Express server, and I feel this is going to affect normal requests.

I wanted to know if there were any other built-in options apart from manually triggering a periodic replication within a setInterval call.

This is how I am currently triggering the replication

```
db.sync(remoteDb, {
    live : true,
    retry : true,
});
```

Comment: CouchDB also supports [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events), which may be what PouchDB is already using. Architecturally I'm not sure how much difference it would make though, unless you have very frequent changes. Is your server memory constrained?